# Trouble initializing solana contract on front-end client

Tags: web3.js, anchor-client, anchor-program-idl, solana-client

I have a very simple program which stores GIFs in a solana contract. Before I can get the gifs, however, I believe I need to call the "initialize" function in my front-end. I have created the logic/button for this, but it is not recognizing "initialize" as a function and is, instead, looking for "startStuffOff", despite me never using this phrase. However, the tests run correctly and I used `anchor idl init` to make sure my idl was up-to-date. I am wondering why the front end can't find my function? I have attached a photo of the relevant code to show thatmy function is called "initialize", my tests are running, and I am using the same logic to try to call the same function on the front-end. The error that I get in the console is `TypeError: program.methods.initialize is not a function`

My relevant dependencies in my package.json are:

```
 "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.25.0",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.66.2"
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly share GitHub repo link so I dig into it and find the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any function called initialize in the image you've attached. There's a difference between having an `Initialize` struct and an `initialize` function. I bet you have a function `start_stuff_off` that calls the Initialize struct in the `lib.rs` file. Replace it with:

```
pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
//rest of the code here
 ...
}
```